# Why Linux chooses shorter prefix? (strongSwan, table 220)

Tags: linux, routing

I'm having 2 following routes:

```shell
# ip ro show table 0|grep 10.250
10.250.0.0/16 via 10.80.1.1 dev ens5 table 220 proto static src 10.80.1.76 
10.250.1.4 via 10.80.1.45 dev ens5
```

The first one comes from table 220 managed by strongSwan, the other one is I created manually for test.

I expect the explicit `/32` route to always win, but

```shell
# ip ro get 10.250.1.4
10.250.1.4 via 10.80.1.1 dev ens5 table 220 src 10.80.1.76 uid 0 
    cache
```

Linux still prefers the `/16`.

Why does it do like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because strongSwan uses policy routing. The missing part to explain this is the output of [`ip rule`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html) with an additional entry set by strongSwan that would typically be:

```shell
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
220:    from all lookup 220
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

The routing *rules* are traversed in preference order (the order displayed above) to reference various routing *tables*, until a route is found (or none (case possible if there were no default route anywhere, or "negative" routes are present) and an error such as `Network is unreachable` is returned). Routing rule pref 220 is run before the standard routing rule pref 32766, so the routing table 220 is checked first. Since in routing table 220 10.250.0.0/16 does match 10.250.1.4 a route was found: route evaluation stops here, whatever could have been chosen in later tables. The *main* routing table is never reached for this destination.

When the result of `ip route get ...` shows an other routing table than *local*, *main* (or the table *default* if it's not left empty as is usually the case), that means there has to be a routing rule referencing this table, and it will be visible using `ip rule`.

For many other [policy-based routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) cases, there would be an additional selector rather than the "wildcard" `from all`. Usually a source IP address/network or an incoming interface is used: again to alter the normal routing outcome. There are even other possibilities, such as port, uid etc. A destination IP address/network is already selected by usual route entries, so would rarely be used as selector in routing rules.

Comment: I think simpler is better. That `lang-shell` is a remnant of the oddball `<!-- language: lang-shell -->` format. `shell` works fine on it’s own with 5 less characters.